# Datediff in same column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get the difference in time between the last two times a person has applied for our service. My solution works, but it's ugly.

Is there a more pythonic way of accomplishing this?

```
for customer in previous_apps:
    app_times = df.ix[df['customer_id']==customer, 'hit_datetime']
    days_since_last_app = [(b-a).days for a,b in zip(app_times, app_times[1:])][-1:][0]
    df.ix[df['customer_id']==customer, 'days_since_last_app'] = days_since_last_app
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of your input dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a list comprehension calculate all the differences in dates of applications then slice it with `[-1:]` so you have a list with only the last element then extract it by indexing with `[0]` is completely unnecessary.

you can just take the last application date `app_times[-1]` and the second last one `app_times[-2]` and take the difference:

```
days_since_last_app = (app_times[-1] - app_times[-2]).days
```

this will fail if there are less then 2 entries in the list so you probably want a special case for that.

*(I'm guessing that line evolved into what it is by trying to resolve `IndexError`s that were the result of not having previous entries.)*

Comment: ahh... Thank you. So much better than mine!

Answer (score 1):

Start by defining a two-argument function that calculates the time difference for you, e.g. `time_diff(a, b)`. Use it something like this:

```
df["last_visit"] = df.groupby("customer_id").apply(
        lambda x: x.apply(time_diff(*x["hit_datetime"][-2:]))
```

(Assuming the values in `hit_datetime` are sorted, which your code implies they are.)

The above "broadcasts" the `last_visit` values, since multiple records have the same `customer_id`. If you prefer you can just store the result as a `Series` with one row per customer:

```
last_visit = df.groupby("customer_id").apply(
        lambda x: x.apply(time_diff(*x["hit_datetime"][-2:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I precisely understand how your data is structured, but the following should provide the functionality you require:

```
df.sort_values(['customer_id','hit_datetime'],ascending=True,inplace=True)
df['days_since_last_app'] = df.groupby('customer_id')['hit_datetime'].transform(lambda y: y.diff().apply(lambda x: 0 if x!=x else x.days))
```